# LINQ querying same table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find all rows where the invoice numbers are the same but there are different cities.

I'm getting an Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool' error when running this code.

```
from DataRowView i in dv
where 
(
  from DataRowView s in dv
  where 
    i.Row["InvoiceNo"] == s.Row["InvoiceNo"] && 
    i.Row["City"] != s.Row["City"]
  select s
)
select i;
```

So on a set of data like {123, Seattle,...}, {123, Seattle,...}, {123, Portland,...} I only want one (in this case) {123, Portland,...} to be returned.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: You can't have a query in a where clause that would return a collection, it needs an expression that returns a bool.

Comment: As is your query makes no sense, you're saying give me all the data rows in dv where it's true that (something that doesn't evaluate to true or false). It would be much easier to help you if you told us what you want to do in English "i want to get all rows that XXXX) as currently the code makes no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to set an error flag on the rows it returns.

Comment: @BenRobinson Better, but note that an `IEnumerable` is not necessarily a collection, and in fact this particular `IEnumerable` *isn't* a collection.  It's important to remember that these LINQ operations return a representation of a query, not the results of executing that query.

Comment: @Servy I understand that, but I couldn't think of a more appropriate way to phrase it. Your comment will elucidate any interested parties I expect ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`where` needs to be followed by a boolean indicating whether or not that item should be included.  You provided a sequence of rows.  That doesn't tell `where` whether or not it should include the item.

You're clearly trying to join this table against itself, to which you're better off using `Join`, and then applying the filter on the joined results:

```
var query = from first in dv
    join second in dv
    on first.Row["InvoiceNo"] equals second.Row["InvoiceNo"]
    where first.Row["City"] != second.Row["City"]
    select first;
```

Comment: So on a set of data like {123, Seattle,...}, {123, Seattle,...}, {123, Portland,...} I run the above code and get 4 results when I only want one (in this case) {123, Portland,...}

Comment: @innov83r Then you need to start by actually describing the behavior that you want in your question.  As it currently stands there is no indication of that whatsoever, nor exactly what behavior you're trying to get even with that example.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll be more explicit in my problems in the future. I'm trying to get the rows that have the same invoice number but a different city.

Answer (score 1):

`where ()` is expecting a `bool`.

`from DataRowView s in dv ... select s` is returning `IEnumerable<DataRowView>`.

From your `( )` you'll need to return a `bool` for that query to make any sense.